# under which situation inequality between two integral yeilds pointwise inequality?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, integral-inequality

suppose I have

$$\int{f(x)} <  \int{g(x)}$$

when I can conclude this : $f(x_{0})< g(x_{0})$ for some $x_{0}$

or is there such a $x_{0}$? how I can find it?

if there is not answer, how about if $f(x)=(ax+bx^{2})c\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=(kx+lx^{2})f\sin(x)$ where $a, b, c, f, k, l$  are constant.

Comment: Unless these are made definite integrals, hard to see what inequality is, because of arbitrary added constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean the standard Riemann integral, over a compact interval $[\alpha, \beta] \subset \Bbb{R}$. In this case, the statement is always true. The contrapositive might be easier and more obvious to prove, namely:

> If $f,g:[\alpha, \beta] \to \mathbb{R}$ are Riemann integrable functions on $[\alpha,\beta]$, and for every $x \in [\alpha, \beta]$, $f(x) \geq g(x)$, then
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f \geq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} g
> \end{equation}

It suffices to prove the special case that if $h: [\alpha , \beta] \to \Bbb{R}$ is non-negative, then $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} h \geq 0$, because once we prove this, by choosing $h = f-g$, the general case follows. However, this is obvious, because all the Riemann sums are non-negative, hence any limiting process also preserves the inequality.

Comment: I meant oposit direction of this in my question!

Comment: if you meant the converse, please edit your question.

Comment: in the question i am asking if the inequality in integral then point-wise inequality your answer is opposite, if point wise then integral inequality

Comment: the statement I made is logically equivalent to the one you made. What I wrote is the contrapositive of what you wrote (i.e same statement written differently)